How can I fix the error loading images in filament 3 when they are not displayed and working remotely?
I just want the database and storage to be remote because we are 4 developers working on the same project.
I have these lines in my enviroment file:
APP_KEY=base64
APP_DEBUG=true 
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=644.211.222.122 
DB_PORT=3321 
DB_DATABASE=47961_a 
DB_USERNAME=admin 
DB_PASSWORD=administrator 
FTP_HOST=644.211.222.122 
FTP_USERNAME=fsfasfdjasklf 
FTP_PASSWORD=cashfjkahs 
FTP_PORT=21 
FTP_ROOT=public/

``and my FTP settings:  
'ftp' => 
`[ 'driver' => 'ftp', 'host' => env('FTP_HOST'), 
'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'), 
'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'), 
'port' => (int) env('FTP_PORT', 21), 
'root' => env('FTP_ROOT'), 
// 'passive' => true, // 'ssl' => true, 
// 'timeout' => 30, 
// Optional FTP Settings... ], `

The problem. I have now is that the database and storage I'm working online, but the program in local, my app is in local and I don't want to take it to a domain, I just want the database and storage to be remote because we are 4 developers working on the same project. The problem is that filament does not show me the preview of the images, we already executed the following commands
php artisan storage:link 
php artisan cache:clear


The real problem is procedural: use GIT (or other version control tool) to manage and coordinate developement flows between differents developers. GIT does just that.
So:
1- each developer works on self-hosted version of the application
2- whenever a feature is completed run a PR (pull request) to GIT and you merge the features in MAIN branch.
3- use SEEDERS to fill key data in DB (via code, not sensible data here)
4- if needed and secure, add to GIT the storage subfolder (via .gitignore configuration).
You'll see the last version of the application if cloning from git the last version of the application from MAIN branch.

remove slash from url
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 

to:
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

